# PHP has whitespace on sides that I can't get rid of?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I have created a web page email contact form in php and then wanted to add this to original webpage but decided to just put all the html from the page into the php file and just run the php file. But there seems to be this weird, inconsistent whitespace on the sides, that margin:0; won't get rid of, and the sae code in html doesn't have any whitespace (just odd text because no php)[Heres a fiddle of that difference](https://jsfiddle.net/8sm22ndb/). Also the whitespace gets smaller as the screen does...then gets big again, then smaller once again [,Here is an imgur album in album of what the screen looks like as you shrink it's width (original screen size 1200px)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scGbU.jpg). I have no Idea why this is happening.

Sidenote: The the actual email function isn't flawless yet but I'm not focusing on that right now.

EDIT: Basically there is whitespace on both sides of the page, I want to get rid of it. Margin 0 hasn't worked and the same code in my index.php file doesn't have whitespace when put in jsfiddle as HTML, so I figured maybe it needs to be done another way for php.

Also I have noticed that when I inspected it, that the whitespace is somehow part of the body??

PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<?php include ('form_process.php');?>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/email.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div id="navbar" class="li flex-container nav hidden-xs">
            <a class="nav-link flex-item " href="index.html#bottom">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="Portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a class="hplogo-a flex-item hidden-xs hidden-sm" href=""><img id="logo" src="Images/WHITELOGO.png" alt=""></a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="Investment.html">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">BLOG</a>
        </div>
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="index.html#bottom">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
                <a href="Portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a href="javascript:window.location.reload();">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
                <a href="#">BLOG</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span id="toggle" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()" class="hidden-sm hidden-lg hidden-md popup">&#9776; </span>
            <div class="container top email">

            <p class="eramble eramble1 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 "> Finding a photographer is a delicate process and you really need to trust your instinct. You put your trust and faith in us to capture your most valuable memories and to tell your story through our camera.  You're here because you feel that my work can represent and accentuate the love between you and your fiancé.</p>
            <p class="eramble eramble2  col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">If this is the case, I would love to hear more about you and about your wedding day.  So, lets start here! </p>
            <div class="email_form">  
                <form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group row">

                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="fname">Name*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Your first name" type="text" tabindex="1" size="30" name="fname" value="<?= $fname ?>" autofocus>
                            <label for="fname" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">First Name</label> 
                            <span class="error"><?= $fname_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="lname">lNAME</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Your last name" type="text" name="lname" value="<?= $lname ?>" tabindex="4" >
                            <label for="lname" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">Last Name</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $lname_error?> </span> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="email">Email Address*</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2" >
                            <span class="error"><?= $email_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="phone1">Phone*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" size="4" maxlength="3" id="phone1" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone1" value="<?= $phone1 ?>" tabindex="3" >
                            <label for="phone1" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">(###)</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $phone1_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="phone2">Phone*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" size="4" maxlength="3" id="phone2" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone2" value="<?= $phone2 ?>" tabindex="3" >
                            <label for="phone2" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">###</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $phone2_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="phone3">Phone*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" size="5" maxlength="4" id="phone3" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone3" value="<?= $phone3 ?>" tabindex="3" >
                            <label for="phone3" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">####</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $phone3_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="message">Message*</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." class="message1 form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" tabindex="5" ><?php if(isset($_POST['message'])){ 
                    echo htmlentities ($_POST['message']); }?></textarea>
                            <span class="error"><?= $message_error?></span> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <button class="btn-default btn rbutton col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="success"><?= $success;?></div>
                </form>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container bottom faq">
            <h1>FAQ</h1>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>

            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer Lastanswer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>





        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <footer class="foot">
                <h6> AVAILABLE WORLDWIDE</h6>      <h6> 2049671111</h6>
                <a href="#">MRPOOPYBUTTHOLE@GMAIL.COM</a>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script>

            function openNav() {
                document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
            }

            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
            }
        </script>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : 1-Nov-2017, 8:56:13 PM
    Author     : BrownBoii333
*/

.error{
    color:red;
}

.success{
    color: #ff9966;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;

}
.visuallyhidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.rbutton{
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
}
.eramble2{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.nav{
  left:50%; 
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;

}

.resize-anchor{
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
}
.hplogo-a{
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
.email_form{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
a:hover{
  color:#D1946F;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link{
  color:#D1946F;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navlink, .hplogo-a{
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding:0;
}
.nav-link{
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Calibri;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 line-height: 26.4px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.sticky {

  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3; 
}
.li{
  text-align: center;

}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 20px;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
}
.top{
  background: #999;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('http://sazan.me/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/26.jpg');
}
.bottom{
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://article.tbdress.com/uploads/2013/06/black-and-white-wedding-theme-1.jpg');
}
.foot{

  text-align: center;
  color: #D1946F;
  margin:25px 0 25px 0;
}
.eramble{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:white;
}
.eramble1{
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.question{
  color: #D1946F;
  font-size: 38px;

}
.answer{
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.Lastanswer{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.popup{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  color: white;
  right: 12px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.carousel-indicators{
  z-index: 3;
}
.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

form_process.php:

```
<?php 
// define variables and set to empty values
$fname_error = $lname_error = $email_error = $phone1_error = $phone2_error = $phone3_error = $message_error="";
$fname = $lname = $email = $phone1 = $phone2 = $phone3 = $message = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fname_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $fname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
    $lname_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $lname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone1"])) {
    $phone1_error = "required";
  } else {
    $phone1 = test_input($_POST["phone1"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed

  }
  if (empty($_POST["phone2"])) {
    $phone2_error = "required";
  } else {
    $phone2 = test_input($_POST["phone2"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed

  }
  if (empty($_POST["phone3"])) {
    $phone3_error = "required";
  } else {
    $phone3 = test_input($_POST["phone3"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
  }    
  if (empty($_POST["url"])) {
    $url_error = "";
  } else {
    $url = test_input($_POST["url"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url)) {
      $url_error = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message_error = "Message is required";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($fname_error == '' and $lname_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone1_error == '' and $phone2_error == '' and $phone3_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'thetalhasuboor@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $fname = $lname = $email = $phone1 = $phone2 = $phone3 = $message = $url = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Can please clarified your question in more details? what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to get rid of the whitespace at the sides of my php file.

Comment: so you do not want both side spacing in our page?

Comment: No I do not want side spacing. I want to content to go from edge to edge.

Comment: What is the content of form_process.php? Open the source view in the browser and inspect it visually, it can sometimes make it obvious where the problem is.

Comment: Actually, is the background large enough?

Comment: I added my code from form_process.php, and what do you mean by is the background large enough?

Comment: have you tried `body {margin:0;padding:0;width:100%}`

Comment: Yes that doesn't work either. This stumps me because in the jsfiddle this has no whitespace

Comment: I think you want to like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8sm22ndb/2/

Comment: yes @ManishPatel that is what I'd like but what do I add to my PHP file to do that?

Comment: your PHP file used for only form validation.. so you can used both in code in same file..

Comment: @ManishPatel yes I know but I still get whitespace. In my question I posted a jsfiddle like yours which has my code and that works, but for whatever reason there is still white space in my php file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to delete the whitespace between the `php tag`?
So you can try the css code blow:

```
.form-control {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

And you can try to delete the `<?php include ('form_process.php');?>`,
may be there is some reason about this.

Comment: There is white space on the left and right side of the webpage, I want it to stretch from edge to edge. My Imgur  album link in question shows what its link at the moment.

Comment: There is white space on both sides of the entire webpage, and i'd like to get rid of it

Comment: So, is the background large enough?

Comment: No its not, it doesnt go edge to edge, there space on the sides